# Setting up Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am setting up Selenium Grid server and I have done successfully on my local machine and I'm wondering how to give the hostname so if other tester wants to register to the hub they should be able to do that, here is what I have done so far:

on my local machine (assuming I will be allowing other tester to register the node here)

Starting a Hub on my local machine:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -hub
```

Starting a Node

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role node  -hub localhost:4444/grid/register
```

I view the status of the hub: localhost:4444/grid/console

Now, my question is: How to register from `another machine`?

on my other machine I have downloaed the selenium-server-standalone jar file and I run this command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role node  -hub localhost:4444/grid/register
```

I get this error:

```
hub down or not responding
```

I know I should not be giving the localhost from other machine and I'm confused here.

Comment: Note: I could not able to post the question if i have `http://localhost` so i have to remove `http://`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the selenium grid as follows

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role hub
```

You can start the selenium node as follows

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role node -hubHost <<hostname/ip>> -hubPort 4444
```

Instead of the string `<<hostname/ip>>`, give the hostname  or ip of the machine where hub is running. If both the node & hub are in same machine, you need to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the IP address of the machine on which the Hub is running.
Check if the IP is routable from the remote "other" machine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of localhost, put your IP : so you should have something like : 
`-hub http://192.168.x.x:4444/grid/register`, or whatever your IP is.

Answer (score -1):

i resloved the issue it was due to jboss which was running on the same server ,Please close the instance of jboss