# how to start working with selenium grid in own machine

Tags: selenium-grid

I am trying to do parallel execution by using selenium grid, in my personal laptop. I did following actions:-

1) Downloaded the latest Selenium Server standalone JAR file that is "selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0" and kept in a folder in my desktop.

2) Tried to setting up a hub in command prompt. Entered the command as below, but it did not work. Commands as :-

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub
-nodeTimeout 600.

java -jar C:\Users\RASH\Desktop\Selenium\Selenium jars\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub -nodeTimeout 600

java -jar C:\Users\RASH\Desktop\Selenium\Selenium jars\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub -nodeTimeout 600

for all the above command it is giving a message as "Unable to access jar files.

Comment: Can anybody help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Could provide more detailed information?
For example, your operation system.

There are a few links:

- [Setting up Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263190/setting-up-selenium-grid?rq=1)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b5lGfBKzj0